# singleton messagebox

Tags: c#, singleton

I am writing an application in which when something happened to the connection I want to pop up a messagebox and show the user the error...

for this purpose when the program throw an exception it will come to the catch block and in that I want to show the user the message here is the code :

```
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (!(ex.Message == "The operation has timed out."))
            {
                  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

As it seems the program will come to this catch something like forever till the connection is become fixed so what should I do to update my message on just one messagebox at a time?

Comment: you can use a static flag you check and set before displaying the messagebox and reset afterwards. Suggestion: do not check the exception message for timeouts, check the exception type!!

Answer (score 0):

There is not much control over `MessageBox` when it's displayed. I would use another `Form` displayed in a modal mode. Before displaying, you can start a separate thread and put the logic to monitor the connection. When re-established, notify the message form and close it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
public static class FailureMessagebox
{
    private static bool _hasBeenSuccessful = true;

    public static void ShowIfFailure(Action someAction)
    {
        try
        {
            someAction();
            _hasBeenSuccessful = false;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            if (_hasBeenSuccessful)
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            _hasBeenSuccessful = false;
                    throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
try
{
   WebResponse response;
   FailureMessagebox.ShowIfFailure(() => response = webRequest.GetResponse());
}
catch (WebException err)
{
   //handle the exception here.
}
```